# Route 53: Is it possible to map two DNS towards two virtual directory respectively on same IP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis-8, windows-server-2012, amazon-route53

I have an AWS Windows Server 2016 with IIS mapped to an ip *x1.x1.x1.x1* and I add two virtual directiories:

First path `[x1.x1.x1.x1/virtualdirpath1]` say `site1` to be mapped to `www.a1.com`

Second path `[x1.x1.x1.x1/virtualdirpath2]` say `site2` to be mapped to `www.a2.com`

I have tried to add `site1` and `site2`'s path in Route 53, but it doesnt allow special characters and allows only *x1.x1.x1.x1* and not the virtual path.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That does make sense, DNS is a name service for hosts -> converts hostnames to IP addresses and vice versa. If you point both www.a1.com and www.a2.com to your webserver, you can then point them to different directories (sometimes called virtualhosts). I has not worked with IIS now for years, but we have documentation online. e.g. https://simpledns.com/kb/144/virtual-hosting-with-iis-internet-information-services

Comment: The link serves for only IIS, but Route 53 details not available.

Comment: I really don't know much about IIS, but in NGINX you can serve a vritual directory as `virtualdirectory.example.com`. Once you have your two vritual dirs mapped to subdomains like this you can add CNAME records in Route53 pointing to these.

Comment: @ArulManivannan, ok, here it is. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-basic.html but maybe you would like to learn about what DNS is and how it works first https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-dns/